# Use $setValidity in ng-repeat input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a form that it repeated in a ng-repeat. I put part of my form in blow.  for custom validation I want to use $setValidity in controller. But I cant to get input name by index in controller. How I use     $scope.form.name1.$setValidity("size", false) and other input element?

```
<form name="form">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
      <input name='name{{$index}}' ng-model="name{{$index}}">
  </div>
 </form>

 function validation(index){
       if(...){
   $scope.form.name.$setValidity("size", false); // form.name0 and form.name1 and ...
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) can be used.

```
$scope.form["name" + index].$setValidity("size", false);
```